Finding $\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}$ 's UMVUE.
Problem
Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n\overset{i.i.d}{\sim} U(\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)$ ,$\theta_1\in \mathbb{R},\theta_2>0$ are unknown . Find $\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}$ 's UMVUE.
My Thought

Easy to show that $X_{(1)},X_{(n)}$ are sufficient for $\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}$ .
Proof that $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is complete, Show that if $E[g(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})]=0$ then $g=0$ . $\mathcal{P}[g(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})=0]=1$
Find the UE of $\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}$ , assuming $E[g(X_{(1)},X_{n})]=\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}$ . Differentiating $\theta_1$ and then $\theta_2$ to get $g(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ .

I get stuck in step 2 and step 3. What I have done:
Let $T=(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ :
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{T}(x,y)&=n(n-1)[F(y)-F(x)]^{n-2}f(x)f(y)\\
&=n(n-1)\frac{(y-x)^{n-2}}{(2\theta_2)^n}
\end{aligned}$$
Assume that:
$$\begin{aligned}
0&=E[g(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})]\\
&=\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}dx\int_{x}^{\theta_2+\theta_2}n(n-1)\frac{(y-x)^{n-2}}{(2\theta_2)^n}g(x,y)dy
\end{aligned}$$
Multiply by $(2\theta_2)^n$ , then I get:
$$\begin{aligned}
0&=\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}dx\int_{x}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}(y-x)^{n-2}g(x,y)dy\\
\end{aligned}$$
First differentiate $\theta_1$ , using Leibniz rule, I get:
$$\begin{aligned}
0&=-\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}(y-(\theta_1-\theta_2))^{n-2}g(\theta_1-\theta_2,y)dy\\
&\quad+\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}dx\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\theta_1}}\int_x^{\theta_1+\theta_2}(y-x)^{n-2}g(x,y)dy\\
&=-\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}(y-(\theta_1-\theta_2))^{n-2}g(\theta_1-\theta_2,y)dy\\
&\quad +\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}(\theta_1+\theta_2-x)^{n-2}g(x,\theta_1+\theta_2)dy\\
\end{aligned}$$
Then differentiate $\theta_2$ , I get:
$$\begin{aligned}
0&=-\left[(2\theta_2)^{n-2}g(\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)+\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\theta_2}}(y-(\theta_1-\theta_2))^{n-2}g(\theta_1-\theta_2,y)dy\right]\\
&\quad -(-1)(2\theta_2)^{n-2}g(\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)+\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\theta_2}}(\theta_1+\theta_2-x)^{n-2}g(x,\theta_1+\theta_2)dy\\
&=-\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\theta_2}}(y-(\theta_1-\theta_2))^{n-2}g(\theta_1-\theta_2,y)dy\\
&\quad +\int_{\theta_1-\theta_2}^{\theta_1+\theta_2}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\theta_2}}(\theta_1+\theta_2-x)^{n-2}g(x,\theta_1+\theta_2)dy
\end{aligned}$$
I don't know how to procede here. Any help would appreciate.
Update:
I find the same question Find UMVUE in a uniform distribution setting . But can I work it out in my posted method?
Upate:
One solution for my step 2 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225580/jointly-complete-sufficient-statistics-for-uniforma-b-distributions. Yet I previously found the Book Introduction to Mathematical Statistics solutions manual (ed 7) claim that this can be solved by differentiating first $\theta_1$ and then $\theta_2$ .
Current question:
About the step 2, can I finish that by differentiating as dealing with $U(0,\theta)$ case?
